# When do you use dynamic finders vs scopes and scope methods in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I saw in the documentation that in ROR 3.2 it's generally better to use scope methods in the model for retrieving records with arguments instead of lamda scopes

> Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for
>   scopes. These methods will still be accessible on the association
>   objects

But when do you use dynamic finders (such as find_by_* instead of scope and scope methods? dynamic finders can also receive arguments and they seem to be simpler to use directly from the view.

If I want to retrieve all the records that have

`attribute1 == [boolean] AND attribute2 IN [array]`

which method is advisable (scope, scope method, or dynamic finder?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You shouldn't be using *any* finders in your views.
2. I would probably write this using a class method.

something like this:

```
class Dog < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :chewed, :color    

  def self.toys chewed = false, colors = []
    where chewed: chewed, color: colors
  end

end
```